# Error in Activator

Tags: java, playframework, typesafe-activator

I have problem with Activator. I'm using **Windows 10** and **jdk1.8.0_65**. I downloaded program **activator-dist-1.3.7**. I set the path and I tried to run my sample program. In **cmd** I wrote `activator ui`. On this website after starting my program receives an error:

Read from **stdout**:

```
download failed: net.contentobjects.jnotify#jnotify;0.94-play-1!jnotify.jar(src)
sbt.ResolveException: download failed: net.contentobjects.jnotify#jnotify;0.94-play-1!jnotify.jar(src)
  at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:291)
  at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:188)
  at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:165)
  at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:155)
  at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:155)
  at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:132)
  at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:57)
  at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$4.call(Ivy.scala:65)
  at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
  at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
  at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
  at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
  at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
  at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
  at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
  at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
  at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
  at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:65)
  at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:127)
  at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:124)
  at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:155)
  at sbt.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:165)
  at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1369)
  at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1365)
  at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$87.apply(Defaults.scala:1399)
  at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$87.apply(Defaults.scala:1397)
  at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:37)
  at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1402)
  at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1396)
  at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:60)
  at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1419)
  at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1348)
  at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1310)
  at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
  at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
  at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
  at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
  at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
  at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
  at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
  at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
  at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
  at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
  at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Read from stdout: (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: download failed: net.contentobjects.jnotify#jnotify;0.94-play-1!jnotify.jar(src)
(*:update) sbt.ResolveException: download failed: net.contentobjects.jnotify#jnotify;0.94-play-1!jnotify.jar(src)
Total time: 4 s, completed 2016-01-11 19:36:12
```

My file repositories:

```
[repositories]
  local
  activator-launcher-local: file:////${activator.local.repository-${activator.home-${user.home}/.activator}/repository}, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  activator-local: file:////${activator.local.repository-C:/Users/Kemer/activator-dist-1.3.7//repository}, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  maven-central
  typesafe-releases: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases
  typesafe-ivy-releasez: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
```

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted (lots of trigger happy down voters who are mostly not knowledgeable enough) - this was a valid question and it just helped me out

Answer (score 2):

I've got similar issue. You have to download this file: https://maven.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/net/contentobjects/jnotify/0.94/jnotify-0.94-sources.jar

then rename it to: jnotify-sources.jar
and put it into C:\Users...\typesafe-activator-1.3.7\activator-dist-1.3.7\repository\net.contentobjects.jnotify\jnotify\0.94-play-1\srcs (if folder srcs doesn't exist just create it)

Hope it helps ;)